# On closing a particular tab it closes all the tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please look into this, on closing a particular tab it closes all the tabs that are open. I want only that particular tab to be closed.

```js
remove = targetKey => {
  let { activeKey } = this.state;
  let lastIndex;
  this.setState(prevState => { 
      const newState = {...prevState};
      newState.forEach((pane, i) => {
          if (pane.key === targetKey) {
            lastIndex = i - 1;
          }
      });
      const panes = newState.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
      if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
          if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
          } else {
            activeKey = panes[0].key;
          }
      }
      return ({panes, activeKey});
  });  
};
```

Check this link
https://jsfiddle.net/yjumr4ox/1/

Comment: Look at the console, it's throwing an error. `newState.forEach` is not a function. I assume you mean `newState.panes.forEach`. Also, instead of using `forEach` it would be better to use `findIndex`, `const lastIndex = newState.panes.findIndex(p => p.key === targetKey);`

Comment: Initially the tabs are open, how to hide those tabs? I want tabs to pop only after click.

Comment: I still get the error in console even after making changes you have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are iterating over all the state at `newState.forEach` and `newState.filter`. You should iterate over panes in the state. like this:

```
remove = targetKey => {
let { activeKey } = this.state;
let lastIndex;
this.setState(prevState => { 
  const newState = {...prevState};
  newState.panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
  });
  const panes = newState.panes.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
  if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        activeKey = panes[0].key;
      }
  }
  return ({panes, activeKey});
});  
};
```

Comment: Yes I have changed to newState.panes.forEach, I get this error in the console-                        Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `11`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: Could you update your jsfiddle link with new content, I think this problem will occur when you add some tabs.

Comment: What do mean by new content? I have updated.

Comment: I mean put your updatet code in the fiddle

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: I can't see any change but the problem about same key 11 is related to add method. when you add a pane instead of set it's key with `activeKye+1` you shoud use a unique key form example you can use `key: Date.now().toString()`

Comment: I will try it once.

Comment: I've implemented here [foked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saeed_shamloo/oL3av5dt/1/) , please check it works correctly or not, thanks.

Comment: Almost got it, one doubt if the tab is already opened, and if we open it again by clicking the add button it should'nt open a new tab instead open already opened tab.

Comment: You mean something like this: [uniqueTabs](https://jsfiddle.net/saeed_shamloo/oL3av5dt/15)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239876/discussion-between-thomas-deepak-konreddy-and-saeed-shamloo).